# Shopware 6 Wish delivery date

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Does anyone know Shopware 6 has wish delivery date (user can chose option when he/she wish receive an order) implementation on checkout entity?

If doesn't is it possible to implement it using custom fields for checkout (btw my shop was builded via Headless Shopware)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such possibility out of the box in Shopware 6 but you can use a custom field for this. Below is an example how to use a custom field on the order entity.

1. Create a new custom field set in the administration. Give it a technical name `custom_order` and assign to Orders.
2. Create a new custom field in the set. Select the `Date/time field` type, give it a technical name `custom_order_desired_delivery_date`.
3. Add a dedicated field to the checkout page using a custom template in your plugin. To add it for example under the shipping date create a file `MyPlugin/src/Resources/views/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-shipping.html.twig` in your plugin:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-shipping.html.twig' %}

{% block page_checkout_confirm_shipping_form %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <div class="my-3">
        <label class="form-label"
                for="myPluginDesiredDeliveryDate">
            Desired delivery date
        </label>
        <input type="date"
               class="form-control"
               id="myPluginDesiredDeliveryDate"
               name="myPluginDesiredDeliveryDate"
               form="confirmOrderForm">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

4. Create a subscriber to save the field content in the custom field when a customer submits the form. To do this create a file `MyPlugin/src/Subscriber/OrderConverterSubscriber.php`:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin\Subscriber;

use DateTime;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\CartConvertedEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Defaults;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class OrderConverterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private RequestStack $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CartConvertedEvent::class => 'saveDesiredDeliveryDate',
        ];
    }

    public function saveDesiredDeliveryDate(CartConvertedEvent $event): void
    {
        $orderData = $event->getConvertedCart();
        $currentRequest = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $desiredDeliveryDateParam = $currentRequest->request->get('myPluginDesiredDeliveryDate');

        if (!$desiredDeliveryDateParam) {
            return;
        }

        $desiredDeliveryDate = new DateTime($desiredDeliveryDateParam);
        $orderData['customFields']['custom_order_desired_delivery_date'] = $desiredDeliveryDate->format(Defaults::STORAGE_DATE_FORMAT);
        $event->setConvertedCart($orderData);
    }
}
```

Register the subscriber in `MyPlugin/src/Resources/config/services.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="MyPlugin\Subscriber\OrderConverterSubscriber">
            <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

5. Clear the cache.

Comment: how it use for headless?

Comment: @Stepan if you don't use the Shopware storefront then you can store the delivery date in a custom field in the order entity.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no existing dedicated field. Using a custom field would be optimal for storing that additional data. Explaining exactly how to achieve the handling of user input and persisting it would probably be out of scope here, as there are multiple possible approaches and it also depends on which checkout related entity you want to add your custom field to.

There's [this repository](https://github.com/vanWittlaer/blog-example-two) (not mine) with an example on how to add a custom field to the address entity and have an input for it in the storefront. You'd have to substitute the `CustomerEvents` used there with a suiting event dispatched when the cart is converted to an order.

To offer one possible approach:

- Add a custom field for the `order` entity
- [Add a subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) with a listener to `CartConvertedEvent::class`
- Inject `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack` into the subscriber
- In the method of the listener use the `RequestStack` to retrieve the user input
- Get the original payload from the event by calling `getConvertedCart`
- Set the data for the custom field from the user input to the payload
- Set the enriched payload to the event by calling `setConvertedCart`

Comment: how it use for headless?